# ngIf - Logical issue with my Angular2 code

Tags: angular

Currently, I have an "ADD" button, once clicked, it shows a new **div** which gives the ability to the end-user to increase/decrease the quantity of the item that was added to cart (think of Amazon cart)

**The issue:** When I click that "ADD" button, I can increase the quantity of a particular item; however, once I increase the quantity of an item, I go to another item, and once I click "ADD", the previous item that I already increased its quantity it disappears!!

**The code:**

HTML: running a for loop of a list of 4 elements

```
<div *ngFor="#item of list">
      <div *ngIf="currentEl === list">
        <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="button" (click)="dec(elem)" value="Down"/>
             <input type="text" #elem value="0"/>
             <input type="button" (click)="inc(elem)" value="Up"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
       </div>
       </div>
<div (click)="addTo(list)" *ngIf="currentEl !== list">ADD</div>
```

JS:

```
    let list = ["Banana", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Milk"];

    export class App {

           addTo(element){      
              this.currentDish = mem;
           }

        inc(elem)
        {
          var nItem = parseInt(elem.value);
          if(nItem < 5)
          {
            nItem +=1;
            elem.value = nItem;
          }
        }

        dec(elem)
        {
          var nItem = parseInt(elem.value);
          if(nItem > 0)
          {
            nItem -=1;
            elem.value = nItem;
          }
        }
      }
```

**What I think:** I think that I have a logical issue on my code, that, I unfortunately not able to figure it out.

I hope you can help, and please if you do just give me a brief explanation to know what's going on and to learn.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. However, currentEl is not defined and the addTo method uses a variable 'mem' that is not defined. I suggest checking your console/debug window for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Every one of your inputs has the same ID:

```
<input type="text" #elem value="0"/>
```

The `#elem` should be a unique value, which it is not when you have more than one item in your list.

---

Instead, run your methods on the `item` and bind your input to a variable:

```
<td>
    <input type="button" (click)="dec(item)" value="Down"/>
    <input id="elem_{{item.id}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value" type="text"/>
    <input type="button" (click)="inc(item)" value="Up"/>
</td>
```

And

```
inc(item) {
    if(item.value < 5) {
        item.value += 1;
    }
}
```

This is assuming your `item` list is made up of objects with at least two fields: `id` and `value`, for example (you don't actually need to use this code, its just for reference):

```
export interface Item {
    id: number;
    value: number;
    name: string;
    // Etc...
}
```

So your list declaration would be:

```
let list = [
    {
        id: 0,
        value: 0,
        name: 'Banana'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        value: 0,
        name: 'Apple'
    },
    // etc...
];
```

Now, whenever you click to increment the item's quantity, your `inc()` function just needs to increment the `value` parameter of the `item` and Angular will connect the dots, changing the value of the input box (as well as any other instance where you display the value).

Neat! And one of the main features of Angular.